# How to turn off warnings for @string resource in eclipse for the Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings

I know it's 'technically' not the best practice to be hard coding strings; but I can deal with it later - right now I just want to get the shell of my projects finished and I'm incredibly OCD about warnings in my code - is there any way to turn this off?

If my title wasn't specific enough take this as an example:

```
        <Button android:id="@+id/aboutBtn"
        style="@style/DashboardButton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="About Vezign"
        android:onClick="aboutClick"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/about_icon" />
```

The android:text="" line would be flagged as a warning for not using strings.xml and referencing it as such.

Preferably something that would turn it off for all future references; and not something I need to type (e.g. @Suppress Warnings)

Thanks!

Comment: Why turn off the warning? Consider it to be part of your "todo" list for the finished product.

Comment: Again, OCD ha - It's not something I'd easily forget, and correct me if I'm wrong - but isn't the use for strings.xml (Apart from using the same string repeatedly in other places) mainly for translation?

Comment: Preferences > Android > Lint or Warnings .. something like that off the top of my head

Comment: I was going by your comment _"I can deal with it later"_. Plus, _"It's not something I'd easily forget"_ is humor, right? I've yet to meet a programmer who hasn't forgotten a "to do" item that wasn't written down. There are other reasons besides translation for using string resources: sometimes you want to use a short string for a small screen but be verbose on a large screen. Similarly, you may want different strings for different screen orientations.

Comment: Ha, true. But interesting; I'll keep the other uses for it in mind for later. Point being though, I'd rather have more important warnings catch my eye rather for now and a lot of my projects I'm just playing around with. Thanks for the tips though!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking >
```

Scroll down to **internationalization**

change the severity of "**HardcodedText**" to 'information' or 'ignore'

Comment: +1 Be aware that this is only available in the latest release of the development tools.

Comment: Why you are trying to update my answer with your blog link? FYI, self-blog promotion are not allowed on Stackoverflow.