# Do I really need to put every string into strings.xml?

Tags: android

I'm tired of getting messages from my IDE about putting another hardcoded string into XML file. I don't understand why should I put it there and make my strings.xml grow large because of every hardcoded string which I *definitely* won't use again or in another place.

Is there any reason why should better keep all strings in XML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to write the strings in the xml. It is optional and it is [possible to disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958266/how-to-turn-off-warnings-for-string-resource-in-eclipse-for-the-android-sdk) those warnings.

But it is a good practice:

- If one day you want to translate to another language or [internationalize](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html), you will have all the strings in same place.
- If a string is used in more than one place and you want to change it, it's easier to change it once in the xml than to edit all the places you use it.

Answer (score 6):

There's no compelling reason to keep internal strings in `strings.xml`, it's for I18N and flexibility.

Literal strings throughout code are a smell, but string constants are fine.

Comment: For who asking about `I18N`: **Internationalization (i18n) is the process of developing products in such a way that they can be localized for languages and cultures easily. Localization (l10n), is the process of adapting applications and text to enable their usability in a particular cultural or linguistic market.**

Answer (score 5):

If you want to support [multi languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html), yes.

And it's much more maintanable to have only one xml file with all your String values instead of searching into your multiple java or xml files if you want to change one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Hard coding strings will not affect the performance directly. It affects the maintainability.

**In case when you hardcode a string and in later stage if you want to change the string "Click me" to "add" or something else, then you need to search your complete project to change the string where and all it is used.**

The main reason that you would get *worse* performance by using a hard-coded string. There are fewer steps involved with hard-coded strings. However, **it is certainly best practice to separate resource strings from application and UI code**.

**So Better to follow strings.xml always. :)**

Answer (score 1):

You can make **multiples files** if you don't want to have a unique large file.

The only things is that all the files must be in the directory **res/values**.
The name of the file is arbitrary and is never used for referring to it.